# Curved arrow in tikzcd

Tags: tikz-cd

I am new to using tikzcd and I want a diagram like this:

```
\begin{figure}
     \centering
     \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge, column sep=huge, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex]
          \displaystyle A \arrow{dr}{F_4} & \arrow{l}{\widetilde{\mathrm{cl}}} \mathscr{E} \arrow{d}{F_1} \arrow{r}{\mathrm{ncl}} & \arrow[bend right=50,shorten >=10pt]{ll}{F} B \arrow{d}{\mathrm{F_0}} \\
    & D & \arrow{l}{F_2} G 
     \end{tikzcd}
\end{figure}
```

The problem is: I want an additional curved arrow (similarly to the arrow F) going all the way from A to G. Is there a simple way?

Answer (score 11):

Just use an `\arrow` command like for the other arrows. Add

```
\arrow[bend right=60,swap]{drr}{X}
```

to the first cell. Moreover, I suggest to use `swap` in some places to move the label to the other side of the arrow (see below for examples).

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge, column sep=huge, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex]
    \displaystyle A
    \arrow[swap]{dr}{F_4}
    \arrow[bend right=60,swap]{drr}{X} % <<<<<<<<<<<<<
&   \arrow[swap]{l}{\widetilde{\mathrm{cl}}}
    \mathscr{E}
    \arrow{d}{F_1}
    \arrow{r}{\mathrm{ncl}}
&   \arrow[bend right=30,swap]{ll}{F}
    B
    \arrow{d}{\mathrm{F_0}}
\\
&   D
&   \arrow{l}{F_2}
    G 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```